# Сcleaner начал застревать минуты на 3 при очистке кэша Firefox, причем только в одной вновьсоздаваемой папке

Tags: безопасность, firefox

С недавних пор CCleaner при чистке начал застревать в этом месте (очищает минуты 3 одну директорию):

`C:\Users\Megauser\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\m321gl1b.default\cashe2\entries`

Шерстит в логах кучу штук типа 015F601F1117708B3BF1BD57CF8256FBCCB38D20, а после очистки просто удаляет папки `cashe2\entries`. После того как захожу на сайты Poloniex Bittrex папки с файлами появляются вновь, по-моему после Poloniex они появляются. Суток вполне хватает чтобы CCleaner застревал в этой папке минуты на 3.

Такого раньше не было, а сейчас появилось, это нормально или вирус какой-то взломать меня пытается?

Comment: А попользоваться антивирусом не судьба? :) Может вы хозяевам сайта биткоины вычисляете и не знаете об этом?

Comment: У меня стоит антивирус.

Comment: Значит не стоит волноваться.

Comment: К сожалению я отношусь к той группе пользователей, которая знает на личном опыте что антивирус это не панацея)